# AdMob does not display ads in case of GDPR (IAB)

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have a custom implementation of IAB, so I write the rest of the keys to shared prefs.
Well, in this case, AdMob does not display any ads.

```
ErrorCode: 0 Failed to load ad:0
```

After some investigation, I found that the key `"IABConsent_CMPPresent"` is the root of the problem. If I remove this key, AdMob starts working. How can I tell AdMob do not track GDPR or do not look into `"IABConsent_CMPPresent"` ?

Comment: Seems like the short answer is you can't, as it is a legal requirement for Google (and you, from the EU) See here for options https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

Comment: The problem was with type of `IABConsent_CMPPresent`, I put string("false"), but AdMob expects boolean(false)